# Drush - /usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success

Tags: 6, drush

When I run any drush command I am getting this line:

```
/usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success
```

For example:

```
[root@061889 ~]# drush
/usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success
[root@061889 ~]# drush cron
/usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success
[root@061889 ~]# drush help
/usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success
```

I've tried rebooting my VPS but am still getting the same issue. This has been discovered while trying to get past a "Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running" error, in case that has any relevance. But, you've guessed it...

```
[root@061889 ~]# drush vdel cron_semaphore
/usr/bin/drush: line 129: /usr/bin/php: Success
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try running $ which drush, and hit the whole location -   something changed in your PHP?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `$ which drush` gives `/usr/bin/drush`. Tried running drush from /usr/bin but getting the same message. Nothing's changed in php. Dunno what you mean by 'hit the whole location', sorry (is this a linux command line term?! Comfortable in command line on Windows, new to Linux command line)

Answer (score 0):

just run

> $ /usr/bin/drush

if it runs it means that your [symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) to the drush command is wrong

Comment: Hi, excuse the late reply and thanks for your help... Running `/usr/bin/drush` gives exactly the same message as in my question